# Php, rewrite URL via htaccess or Explode array of URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my first question around here, so I'll try to be descriptive and everything.

Basically, I want to make a directory structre URL, Like `accessories/watch/gold`.

Now, I got three `$_GET` variables in my file,
one for the accessories one for the watch and one for the color.

How can I make a rewrite that I will be able to get into the page just with accessories OR accessories/watch? It's all via the same FILE.
Now, I have tried exploding the URL since i didn't knew how to make this regExp.

But, when I explode the URL I can INSERT as many slashes as I want into the url like this `accessories////////watch////gold//`, and I want with each word just one slash.

When I tried rewriting, basically it requried all three variables, and one time it didn't but made all the others just empty. I don't want them to be isset. Thanks!

Comment: It would be easiest to just use several rules, one for each url part to match. Or if you wanted to have it dynamic and match any combination, just rewrite `(.*)` to the file and use php to sort it all out using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. To get rid of the empty values from the slashes after explode, just run the returning array through array_filter.

Comment: @Jonathan, I can just add /// multiple to the url how can i fix it?

Comment: for the multiple url you can use regex as `preg_match('/(?P<accessories>[^/]+)/(?P<whatch>[^/]+)/(?:(?P<color>[^/]+)|)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);` the preg_match will return false if not found, and the variable `$matches` will have the 2 (or 3) matches (since the color is optional)

Comment: typically what you would do is if you see multiple `/////` then you redirect to the correct page without the multiple.